# Where to find user related info in google analytics account with React

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am integration google analytics in my site using react-ga package with React application. I am able to initialise the react-ga property code and also send some user info like userId but i am unable find that user info in google analytics account.

Please help me to find out the user info in google analytics account.

[image]

This is how i am initializing the GA code and send user info.I am able to see the pages ion my google analytics account but not able to see any user info(userId).

[image]

I can see the current page but where to find the UserId?

Answer (score 1):

From the left menu, Go to **Audience** > **User Explorer**